# xrdp and xfce4 Ubuntu > 18.04 Unusable

Tags: xrdp, rdp

I'm trying to connect to my Ubuntu VPS (8 core CPU, 24gb ram) using Windows 10 Remote Desktop Connection.  I followed the instructions here:

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04/

It's virtually impossible to do anything.  It's so slow it nearly takes 15 seconds for something to happen like typing in the console or openening up the browser.  I went through many threads here with similar problems but did not have any success.

I tried the latest Ubuntu version as well with no luck.

My Linux knowledge is very limited so will appreciate some assistance here.

Any idea whatI can try next ?

Comment: For a VPS living on the Internet, crypt_level = low is a spectacularly bad idea. The man page xrdp.ini(5) states "This is the only level that the traffic sent by the server to client is not encrypted." Additionally, max_bpp=128 is going in the wrong direction from the default of 32. When I replace the default max_bpp=32 with max_bpp=8, I get a huge boost in performance at the expense of poorly rendered colors on the remote desktop. For server administration, the tradeoff is well worth it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default settings for an XRDP installation are not optimized. To increase XRDP performance try the following:

Make a backup of the configuration file:

```
cp /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini.bck
```

Now edit the configuration file:

```
nano /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

Inside the file edit the variables "max_bpp", "xserverbpp" and "crypt_level", these are optimized values:

```
max_bpp = 128
xserverbpp = 128
crypt_level = low
```

It is convenient to add the variable "max_bpp" the variable "use_compression" with the following value:

```
use_compression = yes
```

Finally, when connecting low, lower the color quality to 16 bits instead of 32 bits.

Comment: This definitely helped but it's not close to the performance I get on Windows servers...

Comment: I hope you guys are reading the [manual](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-xrdp.ini/). The maximum value for `max_bpp` is 32. Also Xorg only supports up to 24 bits per pixel, so the same goes for `xserverbpp`. If you are running an Xorg session (which is most likely the case for many), you gain nothing from changing either of these values.

Comment: @smac89, I agree for xserverbpp (max value 24), but for max_bpp it says if set to undefined or 0 , it is "unlimited" whatever that means.  But anywayy: I do not understand how this should increase performance. A higler color depth ( and I only know 32 as a reasonable limit) should result in more information per pixel transferred to the client, so it should decrease reaction/response time of the remote host.

Comment: @kyodake where did you find the option use_compression?? I did not find it in the man 5 xrdp.ini page? It is simply not defined there....