# xrdp is quite slow

Tags: 20.04, xorg, xrdp

using `xrdp` with the `Xorg` window system to connect from win10 to `ubuntu 20.04` in my local network. The connection is terrible slow. Compare to that a standard rdp connection (win10 to win10) via vpn through the internet is much faster then my local `xrdp`.

```
/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
max_bpp=32
```

After login via xrdp my desktop environment is:

```
~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
GNOME
```

Comment: Did you find any answer useful? Providing feedback is useful for the community.

Comment: most of your links I came across before I start this post. My desktop env is gnome. If you use Xorg for connection, then server/client 32 bits per pixel are highest that is allowed.

Comment: You already found many of the links... It would be useful if you posted what you tried from there, and the result. So others can focus in helping you better.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have same problem, win10 to win10 is smooth all day, but Ubuntu 20.04 to win10 is slow randomly, and very terrible in late afternoon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, I got good performance with these settings:

- xfce4
- xorgxrdp-glamor

In /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini and /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini:

- Policy=UBDI
- max_bpp=16
- xserverbpp=16
- use_compression = yes
- crypt_level=none
- KillDisconnected=true
- DisconnectedTimeLimit=0
- tcp_send_buffer_bytes=4194304

Tweak for TCP (2x request buffer size):

- sudo sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=8388608

see https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1483

Disable compositor:

- xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/use_compositing -t bool -s false

Comment: Made also better experience with a fresh installed Debian 11.7.0 and xfce desktop.

Comment: did not help me. screen just went black after these settings and restart of xrdp service

Answer (score 11):

Make sure to choose your connection speed in your RDP client experience tab. Set it to "LAN (10Mbits or higher)". This enables the RFX codec.

Please see https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/discussions/2136

Comment: Didnt expect this to work, but it solved the problem using the default windows remote desktop client.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you use Xfce4, try disabling compositing with

```
$ xfconf-query --channel=xfwm4 --property=/general/use_compositing --type=bool --set=false --create
```

You could make this setting permanent in `xorg.conf` with

```
Section "Extensions"
    Option "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

You can also work this out via GUI (install it if need be)

```
$ xfwm4-tweaks-settings
```

If yo use KDE, try disabling compositor as well, *Settings* -> *Display and Monitor* -> Compositor.

Also, try using a lower number of colors in the configuration of the client (16 bits instead of 32 bits).

Also, try [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/1283785/226614) options in `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`.

**Related**:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22077/xfce-or-pure-x11-commands-toggle-compositing-immediately-without-restarting-x
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4282/disable-composite-without-restarting-x
3. https://superuser.com/questions/1539900/slow-ubuntu-remote-desktop-using-xrdp
4. https://owendavies.net/articles/install-desktop-gui-on-ubuntu-server/
5. https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1600
6. [xrdp and xfce4 Ubuntu > 18.04 Unusable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283709/xrdp-and-xfce4-ubuntu-18-04-unusable)
7. https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/501#issuecomment-262905321

Comment: For me this setting made in /etc/xrdp/xorg.conf lead repeated to the following symptoms: 1. ssh went inactive, 2. xrdp: many errors regarding ssl-cert, recv, send 3. the computer was completely not accessible, also not physically. It has each time to be rebooted, and the inactive ssh service survived the boot, so I had to start it first via physical interface, before I could access ssh again. After that I removed the changes made to xorg and could again normally log in via ssh. I am using Ubuntu 22.04. So what was your configuration?

Comment: So for now I would be really cautious using that solution.i could have been warned cause I take the warning of the xconf command not too serious, or maybe I overread, because I wanted to have a stable solution. This is unfortunately for me the total opposite. What could have gone wrong here? False section sorting? False Xorg.conf (this is my only one, as Ubuntu works with wayland, afaik...But for xrdp it is the only option that worked on my computers (besides VNC, but that I did not get to work with XRDP, and VNC as a single solution is not fitting my requirements....

Comment: The only thing besides installing xrdp via Ubuntu package manager was to add divers polkit rules to overcome the nasty issues logging in for every service that needs to used (especially colord, wifi-scans, printer,...)

Comment: Is it essential to do the changes not remotely via xrdp, but physically in front of the computer?

Answer (score 2):

Setting "LAN (10Mbits or higher)" in the RDP Experience Tab solved the problem of slowness. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For XRDP you will want to turn off Gnome's Animations:

**Method 1 : Console**

From console run the following as your current user:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

**Method 2 : Gnome Tweaks**

Install the Gnome Tweaks tool:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Run the Tweaks application which was installed.

- Now use the hourglass at the top-left of Tweaks app and search for: **animations**
- Switch Animations to **off**

See also: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/speed-up-gnome-desktop/

Comment: did not help on ubuntu 20.04